# Select three records in a single query of a cross table that contains records of two tables - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a main table called `"product"` that is linked with three tables:

```
"product_type", 
"feature", 
"type_feature"
```

and a cross table called `"product_feature"` that contains several features of the same product.

Example one record:

I have something similar like this:

product_type

```
id_product_type    name
    1              Phone
```

feature

```
id_feature   name
    1         Memory 
    2         Color 
    3         Memory Ram
```

feature_type

```
id_feature_type  id_feature  value
      1              1         16GB
      2              1         32GB
      3              2         Blue
      4              2         Black
      5              3         2GB
      6              3         3GB
```

product

```
id_product id_product_type  price quantity  model
    1           1           100$    5      Moto-G7
```

Cross table "product_feature" (linked to "product", "feature" and "feature_type"):

```
id_feature id_product id_feature_type
    1          1            1
    2          1            3
    3          1            6
```

I want query show this:

```
id_product   type_name price quantity   model    feature_name  value  
    1        Phone     100$     5      Moto-G7     Memory       16GB
feature_name2 value2  feature_name3   value3
    Color      Blue    Memory Ram       3GB
```

I tried this, but only I have only one feature_name and value, and I need three:

```
  SELECT p.id_product, pt.name, model, price, quantity, f.name AS feature, ft.value
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id_product_type = p.id_product_type 
  LEFT JOIN product_feature pf ON pf.id_product = p.id_product
  LEFT JOIN feature f ON f.id_feature = pf.id_feature
  LEFT JOIN feature_type ft ON ft.id_feature_type = pf.id_feature_type
  GROUP BY p.id_product;
```

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with the query I tried, I need three fields with: feature_name  value, feature_name2  value2, feature_name3  value3, If you do not have a record, the field will appear empty or Null, in the example you have to leave the three because it has three features, but if you only have two, the three fields would appear but the last empty or null. Thanks for your help to see if I can solve it.

Comment: What you want in your result set doesn't make any sense.  Instead of columns for feature_name2 and feature_name3 and feature_name, just GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) AS "Phone Features"

Comment: For me if it makes sense, because I need to filter each column the result I can not leave in a field several characteristics I want to show each one independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, It will give you the results:

```
SELECT product.*, product_type.name as TypeName, (SELECT CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(feature_type.value), "|", GROUP_CONCAT(feature.name) ) FROM `product_feature` INNER JOIN feature_type on product_feature.id_feature_type = feature_type.id_feature_type INNER JOIN feature on feature_type.id_feature = feature.id_feature WHERE product_feature.id_product=1 GROUP BY product_feature.id_product) as options FROM `product` LEFT JOIN product_type on product.id_product_type = product_type.id_product_type
```

[image]

You will get options for your product and you have to explode() those options by "|" and you can count how many options you have by using $count= count(explode("|", $options))

By this way you can get all options .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not exactly what I need though it's similar.

I need three final columns that are:
  feature_name value, feature_name2 value2, feature_name3 value3.

I need it to be because I'm working with a "Datatables" library and I need to show the title of each feature in the header

Comment: You cannot achieve this by single query because its not a standard for tabular mysql datasets. What you can do is, you can create a temporary table and insert these records in that table and then you can fetch records from that temp table. After fetching them, you can drop that table.

Comment: Actually the temp table technique mainly use in stored procedures! if you can write store procedure that would be fine in your case! otherwise you can go with my given query as well.

Comment: Hi Abdulrehman, At the end I have changed a little the structure from tables, but I have used your query for construct my query, thank you.